# I can't find TOR icon or app

Tags: onion-services

I want to uninstall TOR but I can't find it. It's not listed in Control Panel - Programs and Features. None of the explanations I've read work. It's still on my computer somewhere because at odd times, when I try to use a url for a web site, the screen goes black and a garbled string of characters appears in the address bar. Any suggestions as to what I can do do to help me find it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser does not get *installed* in the way that most programs do, so it doesn't appear in "Programs and Features". You can simply delete the "Tor Browser" folder to remove/uninstall it.

https://tb-manual.torproject.org/uninstalling/

> Removing Tor Browser from your system is simple:
>
> On Windows:
>
> - Locate your Tor Browser folder or application. The default location is the Desktop.
> - Delete the Tor Browser folder or application.
> - Empty your Trash.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that your operating system’s standard "Uninstall" utility is not used.

---

> when I try to use a url for a web site, the screen goes black and a garbled string of characters appears in the address bar

This sounds like something unrelated to Tor Browser. You should make a new post with a screenshot and more details, and maybe someone will be able to help with that issue specifically.